# Entropy of Pure State Black Holes

Tags: quantum-gravity

Netta Engelhardt's recently gave a talk about pure state black holes, which can be viewed here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOahT4VDQm4

Relying on properties of holographic screens, she argues that even a pure state black hole, despite having 0 von Neumann entropy, must have non-zero total entropy.

Engelhardt never mentions entanglement entropy between degrees of freedom in the exterior of the black hole, even when prodded by Steve Giddings and Gerard t'Hooft.  So my question is this:

***Is entanglement between interior and exterior modes now considered irrelevant for understanding the black hole information paradox?***